# Deleted the Ubuntu file in Windows, but i am still prompted to choose between Ubuntu and Windows on boot

Tags: 12.10, dual-boot, uninstall, 32-bit

I installed Ubuntu using Wubi. I got version 12.10 32-bit. After all was done I noticed a file on my C: drive labeled Ubuntu so i figured when i wanted to uninstall this would be the file to delete. But I have deleted this file and I still get the Menu when i start up my PC that asks me to pick an OS. SO how can i remove Ubuntu from this and just have my PC boot directly into windows?

Answer (score 1):

There their is a small program called EasyBCD for.

http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/

just go to edit boot menu and remove ubuntu and your done.

Answer (score 0):

If you installed using WUBI, you can just use the "remove or edit a program" tool in windows to delete Ubuntu since it is installed as an application.